# Django: How to customize password hint list

Tags: django, django-forms

I was working on `SetPasswordForm` and I was wondering if there's a way to customize password hint showing below password form.

```
Your password can't be too similar to your other personal information.
Your password must contain at least 8 characters.
...
```

I was trying to override it and seeing source code but I couldn't figure out where it comes from.

`views.py`

```
class CustomPasswordResetConfirmView(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    form_class = CustomSetPasswordForm
    template_name = 'users/password_reset_confirm.html'
```

`forms.py`

```
class CustomSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        super(CustomSetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['new_password1'].label = "Custom Field Name"
        ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These hints are coming from below method. `password_validators_help_text_html()` method returns list of hints which are shown below password form.

**django.contrib.auth.forms.py**

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A form that lets a user change set their password without entering the old
    password
    """
    ...
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(), # this help text contains list of hints
    )
    ...
```

You can modify this method as below

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import password_validators_help_texts

def _custom_password_validators_help_text_html(password_validators=None):
    """
    Return an HTML string with all help texts of all configured validators
    in an <ul>.
    """
    help_texts = password_validators_help_texts(password_validators)
    help_items = [format_html('<li>{}</li>', help_text) for help_text in help_texts]
    #<------------- append your hint here in help_items  ------------->
    return '<ul>%s</ul>' % ''.join(help_items) if help_items else ''


custom_password_validators_help_text_html = custom_validators_help_text_html=lazy(_custom_password_validators_help_text_html, text_type)
```

Than add this to your `CustomSetPasswordForm`

```
class CustomSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("New password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=custom_validators_help_text_html(), 
    )         # added custom help text method
```

Comment: Just to be sure, how would this be used? Do you create your own  `SetPasswordForm` class with the method `_custom_password_validators_help_text`, and then you inherit that class when creating `CustomSetPasswordForm` or..? A "full solution" at last would be great to see which things goes where and in what order

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [`password_validators_help_texts`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.password_validators_help_texts)

> Returns a list of the help texts of all validators. These explain the password requirements to the user.

There is another method `password_validators_help_text_html` as well.